# Timezone for android RRule

Tags: android, icalendar, rrule

What timezone does android use to interpret event rrules like `FREQ=WEEKLY;WKST=SU;BYDAY=WE`? I know that if I will change default timezone in device's settings or in calendar's settings the event will be displayed correct so where does he get the timezone for such rrules?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android 2.3:
The timezone in which event was created is located in table `ExtendedProperties`. It has next fields: `_id, event_id, name, value`. Maybe it will be useful for someone.